# replacing 'let' with 'var' without changing the code logic

Tags: javascript

I have a two function, that using a new format. I would like to change this code, but I need that this function did exactly the same.

first function:

```
let sts = $(".st--footer-column");

for (let i of sts) {
  while (i.childElementCount) {
    i.parentNode.appendChild(i.firstElementChild)
  }
  i.parentNode.removeChild(i)
}
```

second function:

```
let groups = $(".st-footer--navigation");

let child = groups.find('.st--footer-column');

if (!child.length) {
  for (let i of groups) {
    let childrens = i.children;
    let stFooterColumn = document.createElement("div");

    // add the class
    stFooterColumn.classList.add("st--footer-column");

    // add each child to the new div
    while (childrens.length) {
      stFooterColumn.appendChild(childrens[0])
    }

    // append the div to previews to group
    i.appendChild(stFooterColumn)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? And have you tried simply replacing it with `var`?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/  might be helpfull

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to replace `let` with `var`? Why do you think that it is a problem in the given code?

Comment: here is a basic definition of [what let is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and here are the [differences between let and var](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/2417602)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Jon Skeet's [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) is also useful. What is the goal of the change? What isn't working about your new version? What makes you focus on `let` specifically? (You also have `for-of`, which was introduced in the same update -- ES2015 -- as `let`.)

Comment: (Just FYI: In English, "children" is already plural, so you don't use "childrens". [There's an unrelated contraction, "children's", but that's a possessive -- "the children's room".])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would leave them as is, but if you want to change them, you can literally just replace `let` and `var` and the functionality will be unchanged, specifically because you are saying they are functions.

`var` is limited to the function's scope, so it won't affect anything outside of the function.

`let` is block scoped, but in the examples you've given replacing with `var` will not affect the rest of the function.

```
function firstFunction() {
    var sts = $(".st--footer-column");

    for (var i of sts) {
        while (i.childElementCount) {
            i.parentNode.appendChild(i.firstElementChild);
        }
        i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
    }
}

function secondFunction() {
    var groups = $(".st-footer--navigation");

    var child = groups.find(".st--footer-column");

    if (!child.length) {
        for (var i of groups) {
            var childrens = i.children;
            var stFooterColumn = document.createElement("div");

            // add the class
            stFooterColumn.classList.add("st--footer-column");

            // add each child to the new div
            while (childrens.length) {
                stFooterColumn.appendChild(childrens[0]);
            }

            // append the div to previews to group
            i.appendChild(stFooterColumn);
        }
    }
}
```